# Chrome Extension to run javascript unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

is there currently any chrome / browser extension to unit test javascript on a page?

just to be clear, i'm not looking to test the extension itself, rather a tool to run tests on the current page.

Comment: What unit tests? Do you want to be able to run a predefined set of unit tests on a random page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in `assert` method of the `console` object in Chrome or most other browsers to run simple unit tests, such as the following:

```
console.assert(!isFinite(Math.PI),"Math.PI is finite",Math.PI)
```

**References**

- [Chromium Command Line API Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api)